# Can you send messages using MSMQ to a machine not in the same domain?

Tags: msmq, distributed, messaging

I haven't read enough about or used MSMQ till now. For many years now, I've only known that they exist. So, forgive me if my question indicates lack of rudimentary knowledge on the subject.

If I have to send a message from machine A to machine B, but they are not on the same network, is it possible to use MSMQ as the message delivery mechanism?

I believe public queues in MSMQ can only send messages between machines that may be geographically far off from each other, but are on the same domain.

Answer (score 4):

I believe in MSMQ speak this is [cross forest support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms705127(VS.85).aspx). More about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/06/27/cross-forest-msmq-you-need-to-be-trusting.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

MSMQ has an optional HTTP transport module (which requires Internet Information Server). With this HTTP transport, a MSMQ server could receive messages sent from 'everywhere'.

[Send MSMQ Messages Securely Across the Internet with HTTP and SOAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164041.aspx)